# Symfony 2: Who is the caller of action methods?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, frameworks

In Symfony 2, where are these action methods, which we implement in controller classes, called?

What I want to do is to observe or maybe modify Response objects that all action methods return.

[Solved]

For my purpose, to observe and modify responses that action methods return, I didn't need to find out who is calling action methods, but I just had to create an event listener for kernel.response (and kernel.view).

Comment: HttpKernel::handleRaw is where most of the controller magic occurs.  It's not the easiest code to read but once you understand it, then how Symfony actually implements it's Request Action Response paradigm becomes clear.  More than worth the effort.  And if you want to modify Response objects then you probably want a kernel.response listener as described in the events documentation.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you for your comment. I could do what I wanted to do by using kernel.response. I was going another way which should have solved my issue as well, but you saved a lot of my time as I didn't have to go deep into the framework source!

Answer (score 0):

**Symfony 2 versions have been deprecated** and not mantained since 2019 (or even earlier, depending on the version). There are  **security issue with some core components**! With that brought to your attention, here is the answer to your question:

Symfony Controller actions are mapped usually in routing.yml and called magically from the Framework :). Depending how your Symfony application is build... The most common way routing entries are added in a Symfony 2.x application are:

- Entries added in the application default **routing.yml** files. In some cases you will find the entries added in the main application folder "PATH_TO_YOUR_SYMFONY_APP_FOLDER/app/config/routing.yml".
- They can also be added in a Symfony Bundle "PATH_TO_YOUR_BUNDLE_FOLDER/Resources/config/routing.yml".
- Routing entries can also be mapped with @Annotations in your Controller action directly

For more information please check the official Symfony docs: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/routing.html

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately we need to maintain this software using a deprecated version of Symfony.

There must be an actual class, or some kind of a base class, that calls those action methods of instances of controller classes. Do you know what class it is?

You mentioned, "called magically from the Framework", however, there is no magic and I believe some class in the Framework does the job.

Comment: Everything in the Software-Development depends on the intentions. While using a Framework, in this case Symfony, the intention is to let the Framework do the magic. The developer should focus on the Business Logic of the application.

Which workflow your Symfony Framework follows until Controller Action Method is called, is a complocated one :) and not relevant (as long not planning to build a Framework your self). There are more than 100 (or more calls) within the Framework until the Controller action is fired. It also depends a lot if the route is public or the user should be logged in...

Comment: A lot depends if the Controller Action is getting parameters injected, which would mean much more calls within the Framework. Each case might be different... Sure is there are 100+ not to say 1000+ within calls within different Symfony Components until your Action Method is called.

As long you're not planning to learn how Frameworks are build, it should not remove your focus from the Business Logic...

Comment: I think I'm getting close. Once I find out my solution, I'll post it here. @alieni, yes, you are right. It seems the annotations are the key for this.